# Django User losing groups (but not permissions) upon login

Tags: django, permissions

We're having an issue where upon login, a user is losing all assigned groups.

Example:

1. I give User a Group through the Django Admin Page
2. The User logs out using the Django logout function, deleting all
   Session data (User still has groups at this point)
3. The User logs
   back *in*, and this is when Group is lost.

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Comment: That's an odd problem that I never saw before. Is there some code in your project that's trying to change the user roles/permissions. Maybe the fault occurs there.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was due to our LDAP authentication system.

Specifically, the AUTH_LDAP_MIRROR_GROUPS setting was set to True, replacing the user's groups with the LDAP system groups, overwriting (and removing) the Django groups.

Thanks!